# repeated Save-operations on MailItem lead to exceptions - maybe due to inline reply feature

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook 2013 Add-In with VSTO.
If the ribbonID is either Mail.Read or Mail.Compose, the ribbon displays a button that does this:

```
Public Sub waitClick(control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Dim insp As Inspector = control.Context

    insp.Activate() '// doesnt change anything for the better
    Dim currentMail As MailItem = insp.CurrentItem

    currentMail.UserProperties("Status").Value = "WAITING"
    currentMail.Save()

End Sub
```

and another button that sets Status to "DONE".
Now, when I trigger either of those buttons more than once they fail on the Save-method and these exceptions are thrown:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" in outlook-add-in-dummy.dll
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll
```

with the message: "cannot be saved because the item has been changed".

If I then try to close the window in which the mail was displayed I am warned about unsaved changes, but trying to save them then yields an error because the mail has been changed "by another user or window".

The documentation on the MailItem.Save-method states that

> If a mail item is an inline reply, calling Save on that mail item may
>   fail and result in unexpected behavior.

So I figure the problem might be with Outlook having what appears to be an inspector window by default to the right (although looping through the Inspector-collection on the Application-object always shows only one inspector) and that inspector somehow interfering/being in inline reply mode.

I am absolutely clueless what to do now. I would very much appreciate any idea.

// the entire behaviour I have described is very much reproducable and not due to a bunch of random interactions with Outlook

// here is a reference-less variant, that yields the same error:
(Curiously enough, it now lets me switch the status field up to three or four times, before producing this error - so I get the feeling this is some kind of unwelcome caching-mechanism.)

```
Dim mailID As String = addIn.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.EntryID
addIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(mailID).UserProperties("Status").Value = "WAIT"
Try
    addIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(mailID).Save()
Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComException
End Try
```

Comment: Okay I have found out by now that the problem probably is due to threading conflicts.

Comment: Somehow Outlook enters into an infinite sync-loop when the UserProperty is changed this way.

Comment: What is the COM exception error code?

Comment: ex.ErrorCode prints "-2147221239" and the Stack Trace is "Stacktrace:    bei Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Save()
   bei outlook_add_in_dummy.ribbon_extension.waitClick(IRibbonControl control)"

Answer (score 0):

The error is MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED, which means the item was modified between the time you opened it and called Save.

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid having messages opened - if you need to make a change, open (e.g. using Namespace.GetItemfromID), make the change, save it, release the reference to the item.

In your particular case, set the property, but do not save the item - if the item is being displayed, it is the user's prerogative to decide whether the item needs to be saved or not.

Comment: I have updated my original post to show you some modifications I have done - I have avoided any references in my code, still the problem persists.
In this case I am afraid it is not up to the user to decide whether the item needs to be saved, so this is not really an option. However, I have tried that and the problem remains! As soon as I reopen the mail, change its status and close and save it more than once I am informed that something else has changed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Then your next best bet is to save when the inspector is being closed (Close event is firing)

Comment: And also track the Write event to add your property (if you haven't done so yet) just before the item is saved by the user.

Comment: I have found when you double click a new email, the first thing to change is "Unread" which is true when an email is new to the inbox (now false).  I found the the PropertyChange event seemed more beneficial than the write event.  Each time I detected a Property change, I saved the email.  In addition to this, I collected all the changes made in my email via inspector and then made my changes late using Namespace.GetItemfromID.  I've been working on my code for months now, but hav finally gotten to a point where I dont see that error any more.